# Extend native JavaScript Number object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

According to TypeScript docs, extending an already existing Interface is as easy as redeclaring it with new properties, and then provide implementation for those. I've used to this technique to add static method extensions to native JavaScript objects a number of times. This however, doesn't work for member functions.

For example ([TypeScript Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20Number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20toPowerOf10%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ANumber.prototype.toPowerOf10%20%3D%20()%3A%20string%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20return%20this.toExponential()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20n%3A%20Number%20%3D%201000%3B%0D%0Aalert(n.toPowerOf10())%3B)):

```
interface Number {
  toPowerOf10: () => string;
}

Number.prototype.toPowerOf10 = (): string => { 
  return this.toExponential();
}

var n: Number = 10000;
n.toPowerOf10();
```

The above code compiles fine, but at run time, it throws the following exception:

`Uncaught TypeError: _this.toExponential is not a function`

The culprit seems to be how TypeScript generates the JavaScript code for this scenario:

```
var _this = this;
Number.prototype.toPowerOf10 = function () {
    return _this.toExponential();
};
var n = 1000;
alert(n.toPowerOf10());
```

It's obvious `_this` doesn't have reference to the `Number` instance here. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if extending native objects in this way isn't supported in TypeScript.

Comment: very interesting question! Using `function () {` instead of `(): string => {` solves the problem for me, does someone know the spec well? Is this desired behavior or a bug?

Comment: @olydis Using an arrow function will capture the outer scope, so this would be expected behavior. If however, you implemented your own Number class with `implements Number`, using an arrow would be fine. Assigning a function to the prototype is the way to go here

Comment: Incidentally, adding functions to the prototype like this is bad practice. They may be overwritten in the future.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's because you use the arrow notation (`=>`) to declare the new function and not `function`. While `=>` may seem like a nice shorthand for the same thing, it and `function` are not exactly equivalent. In particular, `=>` will do lexical scoping, meaning that `this` *outside* of that function will refer to the same thing as `this` *inside* that function, which it accomplishes by capturing that local `_this` in the compiled JavaScript. Here, `this` is the global scope, as you declare that `Number` extension there. If this is a browser `this` will refer to the `window` object, which of course has no `toExponential` method.

To accomplish what you want, simply use the following:

```
declare global {
    interface Number {
          toPowerOf10: () => string;
    }
}

Number.prototype.toPowerOf10 = function() : string {
  return this.toExponential();
}

var n: Number = 10000;
document.write(n.toPowerOf10());
```

Comment: just a small note: explicitly naming the type is still possible (`function(): string {`)

Comment: Also, assuming this is an actual representation of the problem, `Number.prototype.toPowerOf10 = Number.prototype.toExponential;` would be equivalent

Comment: @JulianR Thanks. Worked perfectly. I wasn't aware that ```=>``` had a slightly different meaning. You learn something new every day.

@RGraham This was just a simplification to save space in the question :)

Comment: This no longer seems to compile unless you add a `declare global {` around the interface definition

Comment: Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.