# Extending JS Date using TypeScript but "this" keyword is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript

When using the code below to extend the JavaScript Date type, when calling the new functions it throws an error because the `this` keyword is not referencing correctly, i.e. when I call the `addHours` function the error I get is:

> Uncaught TypeError: _this.getTime is not a function

When I debug I see that "this" is of type "object Window"

This is the TypeScript code I am using:

```
declare interface Date {
    stdTimezoneOffset: () => number;
    dst: () => boolean;
    addHours: (h: number) => void;
    test: () => void;
}

Date.prototype.stdTimezoneOffset = () => {
    var jan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    var jul = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
    return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
};

Date.prototype.dst = () => {
    return this.getTimezoneOffset() < this.stdTimezoneOffset();
};

Date.prototype.addHours = (h: number) => {
    this.setTime(this.getTime() + (h * 60 * 60 * 1000));
};
```

and the .JS file that is created is this:

```
var _this = this;
Date.prototype.stdTimezoneOffset = function () {
    var jan = new Date(_this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    var jul = new Date(_this.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
    return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
};
Date.prototype.dst = function () {
    return _this.getTimezoneOffset() < _this.stdTimezoneOffset();
};
Date.prototype.addHours = function (h) {
    _this.setTime(_this.getTime() + (h * 60 * 60 * 1000));
};
Date.prototype.test = function () {
    return +_this.getTime();
};
```

Now it seems to me the problem is the first line of the .JS file:

```
var _this = this;
```

But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: There is an answer to the issue here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32330345/545230

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extend native JavaScript Number object in TypeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330098/extend-native-javascript-number-object-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using arrow functions. Arrow functions close over the `this` of where they're defined, instead of having their `this` set by how they're called; the latter is important for prototype functions.

Use normal functions instead:

```
Date.prototype.stdTimezoneOffset = function() {
    var jan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    var jul = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
    return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
};
```

---

Side note: When augmenting built-in prototypes, it's a very good idea to create **non**-enumerable properties using `defineProperty` or `defineProperties`. So:

```
Object.defineProperties(Date.prototype, {
    stdTimezoneOffset: {
        value: function () {
            var jan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
            var jul = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
            return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
        },
        configurable: true,
        writable: true
    },
    dst: {
        value: function() {
            return this.getTimezoneOffset() < this.stdTimezoneOffset();
        },
        configurable: true,
        writable: true
    },
    addHours: {
        value: function(h: number) {
            this.setTime(this.getTime() + (h * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        },
        configurable: true,
        writable: true
    }
});
```

*(The `configurable: true, writable: true` is just because that's the default for the built-in properties on `Date.prototype`, so I'm being consistent with them.)*